# Можно ли смеяться о чем-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, глаголы, управление

*Юра пришел минут через двадцать, она видела в окно, как он **смеется о чем-то** с молоденькой медсестрой, стоя у входа в отделение.*
[Е. Горская. Белая невеста, черная вдова](http://ogrik2.ru/b/evgeniya-gorskaya/belaya-nevesta-chernaya-vdova/27400/25-marta-pyatnica/13)

Грамотно ли так говорить? Возможно, появились новые веяния?

Answer (score 3):

Юра пришел минут через двадцать, она видела в окно, как он **смеется о чем-то** с молоденькой медсестрой, стоя у входа в отделение.

**Устаревшая форма управления, в современных словарях не указана, но применялась ранее**,например:

...мы все семь человек уселись около лавочек и... разговаривали и смеялись **о разных обстоятельствах игры**. [Л. Н. Толстой. Разжалованный (Из кавказских воспоминаний) (1856)]

Но потребность в такой грамматике есть, поэтому в последнее время можно видеть ее фактическое использование:

**О чем они смеялись, о чем плакали,** шепча друг другу, неизвестно ― никто не посмел приблизиться, не посмел им мешать. [Софья Пилявская. Грустная книга (2000)]

Comment: Интересно-интересно! А как Вы относитесь к "французской" версии?

Comment: С непониманием.

Answer (score 3):

Это не новое  веяние, а как раз старое восприятие роли предлогов, сейчас возвращающееся.

Многие предлоги ослабляют свое конкретное значение в качестве посредника между глаголами и зависимыми от них объектами. Они становятся простыми грамматическими знаками объектных отношений. За ними сохраняется функция показателей и выразителей того или иного падежа косвенного объекта. Во многих случаях предложное выражение косвенной переходности глагола представляется чисто формальным, лексически не мотивированным (например: жениться на ком-нибудь; выйти за кого-нибудь и т. д.)

В подавляющем большинстве случаев такой переход предлога на роль послелога, на роль «объектной» морфемы при глаголе наблюдается у предлогов с абстрактными значениями. Таково, например, употребление  предлога О:

Предлог о употребляется после глаголов внутреннего восприятия речи,чувства и душевных изъявлений: размышлять, гадать, мечтать, убиваться,спорить, говорить, рассказывать, заботиться, стараться, беспокоиться, жалеть, тужить, плакать и т. п. Глагол смеяться тоже вполне может входить в эту группу. В современном русском языке сочетаемость предлога о  расширяется, охватывая все большую группу глаголов и семантически близких к ним имен существительных.

В литературном языке XVIII — начала XIX в. глагол смеяться (ср. ругаться и пр.) сочетался не только с беспредложным дательным падежом и с предлогом над и творительным падежом, но и с предлогом о и предложным падежом. Ср. у Пушкина: «Не смейся горестям моим» - Д.п, «И посмеяться кой **о** чем» - П.п.;

Однако уже Н. И. Греч признавал лишь две конструкции при глаголе смеяться: конструкцию с дательным падежом, когда «управляемым именем означается предмет не личный, вещественный или отвлеченный», и более употребительную конструкцию с предлогом над и творительным падежом.

Ф. И. Буслаев в своей «Исторической грамматике» считает «более обыкновенной» конструкцию с предлогом над. Но К. С. Аксаков в своей рецензии упрекал Буслаева за то, что тот не выяснил внутреннего различия между смеяться — посмеяться над чем и о чем: «Смеяться над чем значит: делать из чего-нибудь предмет, цель смеха; смеяться о чем значит: делать из чего-нибудь повод к смеху, смеяться ради чего».

Так что если разобраться в смысле фразы, то предлог о указывает на повод к смеху, а над - на цель, предмет осмеяния.

*Юра пришел минут через двадцать, она видела в окно, как он смеется о чем-то с молоденькой медсестрой, стоя у входа в отделение.*  Смысл: разговаривали о чём-то весело, со смехом, а вот если бы они смеялись **над** чем-то, здесь бы присутствовал предмет осмеяния. Эта фраза не просто грамотна, но она логически более верна и продуманна. Если писатель серьёзный, он выберет именно этот предлог, а не более распространённый НАД

Comment: Ёмко и убедительно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Как ни странно, это не новое, а вполне себе классическое веяние (возможно, калька с французского ***se rire de***). Корпус:

...и смеялся о некоторых персонах. [Е. П. Карнович. Придворное кружево (1884)]

...и смеялись о разных обстоятельствах игры. [Л. Н. Толстой. Разжалованный (Из кавказских воспоминаний) (1856)]

Дальнейшие примеры в корпусе встречаются года с 2000.

В пользу того, что это заимствованная (предположительно, из французского)  конструкция, косвенным образом говорит и ее неупотребимость в настоящем и будущем временах, а также ненаблюдаемость вариации с предлогом "об".

Answer (score 0):

**СМЕЯТЬСЯ,** 2. **над кем-чем; (устар.) кому-чему.** Насмехаться, издеваться над кем-, чем-л. С. над собой. С. над глупостью. С. над доверчивостью. С. над приятелями.

1) Итак, **словарь позволяет нам смеяться только над чем-то/кем-то** (практически высмеивать что-то или кого-то). Такой своеобразный юмор: кто-то поскользнулся и упал, это так смешно.

Дети, товарищи его, **смеялись над ним** и дразнили. [Марина Дяченко, Магам можно все (2001)]

**Смеялись над бабушкой**, которая неловко встала и уронила тяжелую сумку. [Лев Дурнов. Жизнь врача. Записки обыкновенного человека (2001)]

Как мы смеялись **над стариком Гештом,** который, угощая нас ужином в одном из греческих ресторанчиков, старательно подсчитывал, какое вино дешевле. [Евгений Велтистов.  (1978-1979)]

2) Предлог **кому/чему объявили устаревшим,** а ведь он обозначал **причину смеха:**  можно было смеяться словам, шуткам, анекдотам.

Сейдахмат что-то громко рассказывал. Сидевшие **смеялись его словам**.  [Чингиз Айтматов. Белый пароход (1970)]

3) **О предлоге О вообще не говорится,** но предлог этот особый. Он обозначает общую тему, а не конкретный предмет: разговаривали и смеялись о чем-то (обратим внимание **на местоимение**!)

...они вдвоем тянули бы кофе, **смеялись о пустяках,** ...[Улья Нова. Инка (2004)]

Существительные не так часто сочетаются с предлогом О: **можно смеяться о чем-то, но пока нельзя смеяться о вчерашней вечеринке.**

**И вывод:** желательно расширять сочетаемость глагола ***смеяться*** с разными предлогами, а не использовать только предлог НАД.

**Над кем смеетесь? Над собой смеетесь!** В оригинале: **Чему смеетесь? Над собою смеетесь!** Из комедии «Ревизор» (1836) Н. В. Гоголя (1809—1852), слова Городничего (действ. 5, явл. 8).